# crazy values for window.outerWidth

Tags: javascript, html

window.outerHeight / window.outerWidth

are this values not in pixels ?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_inner_outer

(screen is 2560)
firefox outerWidth: 2576
edge outerWidth: 3435
chrome outerWidth: 2560
IE outerWidth: 2862

what are this values ?

how can i get the screen size in pixels ?

Answer (score 1):

//if you need the screen width and height

//Screen height

```
var height = screen.height
```

//Screen Width

```
var width = screen.width
```

//if you want to know what the code you use do:

Get the window's height and width: (including toolbars/scrollbars):

```
var w = window.outerWidth;
var h = window.outerHeight;
```

source:http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_outerheight.asp

Get the window's height and width: (NOT including toolbars/scrollbars):

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

Comment: what i need in the end is the width and height of a canvas which i should get with window.innerHeight/width and i need to track mouse coordinates any way outerWidth gives me 3000+ values on a screen which has a physical resolution of 2560 innerValue and mouse tracking gives me also crazy values chrome seams to work fine all other browsers give me impossible values

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your doctype at the top of your HTML, I remember this was giving me an issue awhile back. Try putting

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

before your opening  tag

Answer (score 0):

Grrrmppf

i not realy use IE or edge and chrome behaves different eg ZOOM is on a domain level in opposite to ie and edge where it is on a global level

problem was i had pagee zoom on