# Why does window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight report a value slightly larger than the actual size of the browser?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I have a browser window whose size is 400x600 pixel, yet, if I query `window.outerWidth`, it returns 410 and `window.outerHeight` returns 605. That is on Firefox 72.0.2.

With Chrome, the reported values are 414 and 607, respectively.

I thought that `window.outerWidth/Height` are supposed to return the size of the browser window.

*edit*, I was given three links that supposedly answer my question. Yet they don't.

Comment: I fail to see how the *has already an answer link* answers my question. My question has nothing to do with `innerWidth`.

Comment: innerWidth AND outerWidth - so click on one of the hundred other dupes for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175086/crazy-values-for-window-outerwidth)